# Многопоточный захват видео python

Tags: python, многопоточность, opencv

Стоит задача: захватывать несколько потоков с камер.
Хочу реализовать класс, где будут методы, по захвату потока, показ окна камеры, начало записи в файл, остановка демонстрации, записи
использую opencv, treading

Создаю класс

```py
class VideoRecorderThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, camName, src):
        super().__init__()
```

Создаю экземпляры класса, после этого вызываю `start()` для каждого экземпляра, которые вызывают метод

```py
def run(self):
    while self.open:
        if self.video_cap.isOpened():
            self.ret, self.frame = self.video_cap.read()
```

Вопрос, выходит, что в потоке находится только этот метод, как тогда для этого экземпляра класса сделать, чтобы и другие методы тоже работали в потоках, чтобы обращаться методам других экземпляров и к основному потоку? Каждый метод в поток? - звучит странно. Использовать не `treading`?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Непонятно, что вы в принципе хотите. Что за другие методы, что значит "обращаться", зачем обращаться? Если ваш метод run успешно работает в отдельном потоке - что вам мешает написать в нём всю желаемую вами логику, в том числе и вызовы других методов?

Comment: Есть несколько ip камер, нужно собирать с них видео, но необходим функционал, чтобы только просматривать камеры, только записывать, и то и то одновременно, чтобы с камеры был сделан был скрин. Для этого в основном потоке крутится в цикле простое меню и через него обращение к разным методам класса. Вот думал, над решением, что вся логика в одном методе, но...как-то странно что ли выглядит.